# Is there any way to find out where in a piece of code a dll is referenced visual studio C++

Tags: c++

Im trying to find out where in my code is referencing ucrtbased.dll

And before you ask, no I am not running in debug mode.

It seems like its this library causing the issues. https://github.com/benhj/glfreetype

Edit number 2:
It is freetype specificaly causing issues.

Comment: First you should find which function is referenced - it is possible by deleting reference to the dll as then linker will scream for lacking some symbol at compilation. Then you'll need to search for the function. Though the dll might be imported via another third party your code relies upon and your code might not have any direct references/uses at all.

Comment: Another option is to somehow figure out which header is associated with the library. With this you can find where is it is included and comment it out to let compiler scream for undefined function.

Comment: the dll im looking for is a file that should only be referenced in debug mode. Im wondering if there is some kind of addon for visual studio that can find where a dll is referenced from

Comment: `ucrtbased.dll` That is the debug build of the Windows Universal CRT. Any C/C++ code compiled with MSVC `/MDd` will reference it in the debug build (until you go to great lengths to avoid linking any C runtime at all).

Comment: the problem is that I am not running in debug mode

Comment: Then you link to the debug build of some other library that uses the CRT. However, that would normally give you at least a linker warning. Check the option to generate a mapfile in the linker settings and look in the .map file to see what module references `ucrtbased`.

Comment: I tried making a map file, but ucrtbased.dll did not show up

Comment: Then you should be able to figure out what other library references it using the outdated [Dependency Walker](https://www.dependencywalker.com/) or the still rough around the edges [Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies).

Comment: huh. They both didnt show ucrtbased as an included file

Comment: At this point you should really [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63212404/edit) your post and fill-in all the missing details - what project you build with which settings, what external libraries you link to, where does `ucrtbased` come into picture etc.

Comment: Ok I finally figured out what library seems to be causing the issue. https://github.com/benhj/glfreetype

Comment: My guess is you followed the instruction on the web page `mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make`  and built only the debug configuration instead of all configurations.